# Switch to Ruby 2.3.0 (from 2.0.0) creates issue on Active Record validates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I recently switched my Rails 4.2 app from ruby 2.0.0 to 2.3.0 and when I start my rails server ($ rails s), a new notifcation just appeared

```
/home/app/models/user.rb:127: warning: key :numericality is duplicated and overwritten on line 128
/homeapp/models/user.rb:127: warning: key :on is duplicated and overwritten on line 128
/home/app/admin/user.rb:142: warning: key :collection is duplicated and overwritten on line 147
/home/app/models/deal.rb:223: warning: key :numericality is duplicated and overwritten on line 226
/home/app/models/deal.rb:234: warning: key :numericality is duplicated and overwritten on line 237
```

Here is an example of the line causing issues, they are the ones where on creation of the account I set the attribute nb equal to 3 (on: :create), and the user, in the life of his account, can grow his number of permissions but will never be able to have more than 7 (on: :update).

```
validates :nb_of_permissions,
            presence:true,
            numericality: { equal_to: 3 }, on: :create,               
            numericality: { less_than_or_equal_to: 7 }, on: :update
```

What should I change ?

Thanks

Comment: The issue/bug was always there. It's just that now you can see it. :)

Comment: I had this feeling:) thanks Rails/ruby for strong conventions and notifications:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference here is that the Ruby upgrade is telling you about a 
bug in your app that was previously passing unnoticed. Only the second `numericality: { less_than_or_equal_to: 7 }, on: :update` was ever really used.

```
irb(main):001:0> { foo: 1, foo: 2 }
(irb):1: warning: key :foo is duplicated and overwritten on line 1
=> {:foo=>2}
```

Use `validates :att, {}` when you have relatively simple conditions.
Since your validations apply to different lifecycle events you should declare each as a separate validation.

```
validates :nb_of_permissions, { presence: true }
validates_numericality_of :nb_of_permissions equal_to: 3, on: :create 
validates_numericality_of :nb_of_permissions less_than_or_equal_to: 7, on: :update
```

---

Testing model validations base bones is actually pretty easy (although not as slick as with Shoulda-Matchers):

```
RSpec.describe Thing do
  describe "validations"
    describe "#nb_of_permissions" do
      context "when updating" do
        let(:thing) { Thing.create(nb_of_permissions: 3) } 
        let(:errors) { thing.valid?.errors[:nb_of_permissions] }
        it 'is must be present' do
          thing.nb_of_permissions = nil
          expect(errors).to include 'must be present.'
        end
        it 'is must be at least 7' do
          thing.nb_of_permissions = 10000
          expect(errors).to include "must be less than or equal to 7"
        end
      end 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: PS. You should really have a test somewhere that ensures that both validations are applied to `nb_of_permissions` if it is important to your app.

Comment: @Mathieu: Guess your tests didn't quite test anything :)

Comment: Ok. in that case you should comment out both lines and make sure you have at least two test failures as your tests are not covering it at all.

Comment: actually i had tests but commented out as i never managed to make them work for the on: update. it was sth like : validate_numericality_of(:max_nb).only_integer.is_less_than_or_equal_to(90).on(:update) / fails and other people have the same problem: 
https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/678

Comment: Added an example of how to do a model validation test without shoulda-matchers. If you are using FactoryGirl you can use `build_stubbed` for the updating scenario as it fakes persistence so the the `on: update`validation is called.

Comment: Its the same basic approach in minitest. Setup a model and call `.valid` and write assertions about the messages in the errors hash.

Comment: @max thanks a lot for the suggestions and update without shoulda-matchers

Answer (score 3):

You should try this

```
validates :nb_of_permissions, presence:true, numericality: { equal_to: 3 }, on: :create
validates :nb_of_permissions, presence:true, numericality: { less_than_or_equal_to: 7 }, on: :update
```

Comment: cool it worked. just a corrolary question: then if on create I have presence: true, if implies that on update it if of course already present then maybe on your second suggestion line on update, I would not need to validate again that presence = true?

Comment: No, you either seperate the presence and numericality validations like in my answer or you add the presence validation to both. If you remove  `presence: true` on the second line it will let you update with a nil value for `nb_of_permissions` due to the way `validates_numericality_of` works.

Comment: You do need to test for presence if it's necessary to exist. After all nb_of_permissions could potentially be set to null before calling update.

Answer (score 3):

Your old code was buggy, and not doing what you think it was. There has been no change in behaviour here; you are just being shown a helpful warning to highlight the probable mistake!

Consider the following simple example:

```
hash = {a: 1, a: 2}
```

In ruby versions 2.0 *and* 2.3, this is equivalent to just defining:

```
hash = {a: 2}
```

...Because the hash key gets overridden. Likewise, your code:

```
validates :nb_of_permissions,
            presence:true,
            numericality: { equal_to: 3 }, on: :create,
            numericality: { less_than_or_equal_to: 7 }, on: :update
```

...Is, and always was, equivalent to just writing:

```
validates :nb_of_permissions,
            presence:true,
            numericality: { less_than_or_equal_to: 7 },
            on: :update
```

[There is more than one way to do it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it), but for example you could fix this bug by defining **two** validations, such as:

```
validates :nb_of_permissions,
            presence:true,
            numericality: { less_than_or_equal_to: 7 },
            on: :update

validates :nb_of_permissions,
            presence:true,
            numericality: { equal_to: 3 },
            on: :create
```